# issue with WordNetLemmatizer() when using a list of tuples

Tags: python, nltk, stemming, lemmatization

I find out that there is a difference in the way we pass an argument to `WordNetLemmatizer()`

When I run:

`m=[('recurrances', 'NNS')]`

`wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()`

`print '>>>>', wnl.lemmatize(m[0][0], 'n')`

the result is "recurrances", but when I run:

`print '>>>>', wnl.lemmatize('recurrances', 'n')`

the result is what I expect >> "recurrance"

Why is it like this? 
Is there any way to get the correct result (i.e. the singular form) in the first case?

Comment: Try stemming...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the difference you are talking about between passing m[0][0] or the string directly (and it would really surprise me if there was one, it's probably due to something else in your code).

The fact that it does not return what you may expect, could be due to wordnet not recognizing the word you are feeding its lemmatizer. Suboptimal solution, but you can work around this, as @alvas suggests, by using a stemmer instead. A bit more rudimentary, but also more robust.
Something like the following:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
snowball_stemmer = SnowballStemmer('english')

m=[('recurrances', 'NNS')]
wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
print(wnl.lemmatize(m[0][0], pos='n'))
print(wnl.lemmatize('recurrances', pos='n'))

word = m[0][0]
if wordnet.synsets(word):
    lemma = wnl.lemmatize(word, pos='n') # you might want to do pos-tagging if you have the whole sentence to not always pass it pos-tag n...
    print('Lemma:', lemma)
else:
    stem = snowball_stemmer.stem(word)
    print('Stem:', stem)
```

Output (where, as you can see, the first two lines are identical):

```
recurrances
recurrances
Stem: recurr
```